# how to associate different lists in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint and am trying to create lists and list forms in sharepoint 2010

I have 2 lists, list A and list B.  In list A, I have a lookup field that point to list B.  And same as in list B, I have a lookup field that point to list A.  Their relations are many-to-many.

The ideal world is when user updates "item 1" in list A and associates it with "item A" in list B.  I want it to automatichally add the same association to "item A" in list B.  In another word, "item A" in list B will automatically have an association to "item 1" in list A even user doesn't go to the list B edit form to add it there.

I'm not sure if I explain it clear enough.  If not, please let me know and I'll try again.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: SharePoint is a poor candidate for handling many to many relationships, like this. Is there any possibility of moving this data to a database and using a proper cross-join table?

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't.  Database is not an option for this project.  any other workaround?

Comment: No, SharePoint lists are not relational databases, and cannot maintain any sort of data integrity with a many to many relationship. Best bet is to rethink the design of these two lists to see if you can achieve your goal with a different list arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using CSOM/REST API.

When adding or editing items in LIST A, add JS code to trigger an onSuccess-like function that will add or update the related item in LIST B. You will need to utilize the ID column that is automatically created for list items.

If you really want you could do the same for LIST B, to create a pseudo-relationship between the two lists.